# How to combine elements of two lists using scala?

Tags: scala

I have following lists:

```
val list1 = List(
    (List("pune"),"myname1","myId1", "myAdd1"),
    (List("pune"),"myname2","myId2", "myAdd1"),
    (List("pune"),"myname3","myId3", "myAdd3"),
    (List("mumbai"),"myname2","myId1", "myAdd2")
)

val list2 = List(
    ("pune","myAdd1"),
    ("mumbai","myAdd2")
)
```

I want following output-

```
List(
    (List(pune),"myname1","myId1", "myAdd1"),
    (List(pune),"myname2","myId2", "myAdd1"),
    (List("mumbai"),"myname2","myId1", "myAdd2")
)
```

How do I get above output using scala?

Comment: I don't think this example alone is sufficient to describe the logic you want to encode. Can you explain more?

Comment: Do you really mean lower case "add" in list2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you want, but I think it's to use `list2` to filter `list1` by the first and fourth fields in the tuples?

```
val list1 = List(
  (List("a1"), "b1", "c1", "d1"),
  (List("a1"), "b2", "c2", "d1"),
  (List("a1"), "b3", "c3", "d3"),
  (List("a2"), "b2", "c1", "d2")
)

val list2 = List(
  ("a1", "d1"),
  ("a2", "d2")
)

list1.filter({
  case (a::Nil, b, c, d) =>
    list2.contains((a, d))
  case _ =>
    false
})

/*
Result:
  List(
    (List(a1),b1,c1,d1),
    (List(a1),b2,c2,d1),
    (List(a2),b2,c1,d2)
  )
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 val list1 = List(
 (List("pune"),"myname1","myId1", "myAdd1"),

     (List("pune"),"myname2","myId2", "myAdd1"),

     (List("pune"),"myname3","myId3", "myAdd3"),

     (List("mumbai"),"myname2","myId1", "myAdd2"))

 val list2 = List(("pune","myAdd1"),("mumbai","myAdd2"))

 list1.filter(x=> list2 contains ((x._1(0), x._4)))
 // List((List(pune),myname1,myId1,myAdd1),
 //      (List(pune),myname2,myId2,myAdd1),
 //      (List(mumbai),myname2,myId1,myAdd2))
```

But really this is just a minor variation of several questions you've asked previously. I would hope you could learn enough from those other answers to be able to work this sort of thing out yourself.